# Chartjs: Overwrite plot y-axis integer labels to some string value

Tags: chart.js

I have created a line chart , with 3 datasets.
the y-axis (which indicates `rating`) will be in range from `[0-4]` only and can never be greater than `4`.

I need to convert the integer label to some random text , like
`1 = slow`, `2 = average` and so on..
how can I override the default label?

```
            scaleBeginAtZero: true,
            animation: true,
            animationEasing: "linear",
            bezierCurve: true,
            showTooltips: true,
            scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
            scaleShowLabels: true,
            scaleType: 'date',
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the `ChartJs` `Y-axis` label , instead of passing string to `scaleLabel` property we need to pass the closure function, which will modify the label text.

```
scaleLabel: function (value)
                {
                    var label = "";
                    switch (parseInt(value))
                    {
                        case 1:
                            label = "Slow";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            label = "Avg.";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            label = "Fast";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            label = "Exp.";
                            break;

                    }
                    return label;
                }
```

[image]

> This is undocumented feature of `chartJs`